# Why do we need to use dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, pointwise-convergence

I was thinking of this problem:
If $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. and $\lvert f_n\lvert \leq g$ for some $g\in L^p$, then prove that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$.

To use the dominated convergence theorem we need:
1. $\lvert f_n -f\lvert^p\rightarrow 0$ a.e.
2. $\lvert f_n -f\lvert^p \leq G(x)\in L^1$.

The first condition we can directly get from the pointwise convergence, and to get the second condition, we let $G(x)=2^pg(x)^p\in L^1$, and then we have $\lvert f_n-f \lvert^p\leq [2g(x)]^2=G(x)\in L^1$. So we can get the desired result.

However, I don’t understand why we cannot go directly from $\lvert f_n -f\lvert^p \rightarrow 0 $ a.e to $\int \lvert f_n-f\lvert^p\rightarrow 0$?

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Because it is not true in general that point-wise convergence implies convergence in norm.

Comment: For example, if $f_n$ is $1$ on $[n,n+1]$, and $0$ elsewhere, then $|f_n|\rightarrow 0$ everywhere, but $\int|f_n|=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Why is $|f_n-f|\le 2g$?

Comment: @amsmath because $\lvert f_n-f \lvert\leq \lvert f_n \lvert + \lvert f \lvert$, and both are bounded by g

Comment: @TonyK, oh that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not true in general that point-wise convergence implies convergence in norm. You can have continuous functions $f_n$ tending to zero but the integrals do not. For example, take as $f_n$ a function whose graph is a triangle whose vertices are the points $(n,0),(n+1,0),(n+\frac{1}{2},1)$, and zero elsewhere. Then $f_n(x)\to 0$ for every $x\in [0,\infty)$, but $\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}$ for every $n$, so you get a counterexample in $L^p(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!